# salto de linea entre 2 tr

Tags: html, table

¿Se puede poner un `<br>` adentro de una `<table>` entre 2 `<tr>`?

Tengo una tabla y tengo los `<tr>` muy pegados y quisiera ponerles un salto de linea pero cuando uso el `<br>` no se aplica el salto de linea. Hay alguna otra forma?

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="6" scope="col">EQUIPOS</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row2">Marca</th>
            <th scope="row2">Num. Serie</th>
            <th scope="row2">Modelo</th>
            <th scope="row2">Procesador</th>
            <th scope="row2">RAM</th>
            <th scope="row2">Cant. RAM</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <!--salto aqui-->
          <tr>
            <th scope="row2">Almacenamiento</th>
            <th scope="row2">Pulgadas</th>
            <th scope="row2">Sistema operativo</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Y un padding no te sirve?? Pon todo el código para ver el ejemplo completo.

Comment: con un padding o margin te serviría, si usas el br se hace el salto de línea encima de toda la tabla...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer el salto de línea con `<br>` entre las columnas de tu tabla, el salto de línea ocurrirá encima de tu tabla:

```html
<span>Mi tabla:</span>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 1</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 2</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 3</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 4</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 5</th>
  </tr>
  <!--Salto de linea aqui-->
  <br><br><br><br>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que podrías hacer agregarle una columna vacía que ocupe todo el ancho de la tabla y darle una altura:

```html
<span>Mi tabla:</span>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 1</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 2</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 3</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 4</th>
    <th scope="row2">Columna 5</th>
  </tr>
  <!--Salto de linea aqui-->
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 10px" colspan="16"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O si gustas darle un padding a la primera columna (o cabecera):

```html
<span>Mi tabla:</span>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding-bottom: 10px" scope="row2">Columna 1</th>
    <th style="padding-bottom: 10px" scope="row2">Columna 2</th>
    <th style="padding-bottom: 10px" scope="row2">Columna 3</th>
    <th style="padding-bottom: 10px" scope="row2">Columna 4</th>
    <th style="padding-bottom: 10px" scope="row2">Columna 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
    <td>fila 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
    <td>fila 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Serviría añadir un padding a la fila "de abajo" para que quede más separada de la que está encima?

Comment: @Alfabravo justo edité mi respuesta haciendo eso jeje

Comment: Me gusta más, es menos "hechizo" :)